# Counting bits in an array

Tags: algorithm

Given that we know how many bits are set in N elements that is if say we have  array A and array of array B .

```
A store element 
B[i] store positions of bits set corresponding to A[i].
```

Then question is can we find how many bits are set in sum of all A[i] for 1<=i<=N using this B array.

Like say we have A=[700,40]

```
As 700 is 1010111100 so we have [2 3 4 5 7 9]
As 40 is 101000 so we have [3 5]
```

B is [[2,3,4,5,7,9],[3,5]]

And we want count of bits set in 740.

How this can be done in efficient way ? Please help

Comment: I can see you are stressed, but please - calm down and write your question in more understandable english, I cannot figure out what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @amit Yeah right. I am stressed and whats not understanding in this question ?

Comment: yes you can its just like adding numbers in binary representation

Answer (score 1):

This is about binary addition. In your example

```
     A[0] = 1010111100    B[0] = [2,3,4,5,7,9]
     A[1] = 0000101000    B[1] = [3,5]
A[0]+A[1] = 1011100100
```

So the sum is represented as [2,5,6,7,9]. Can you see how to get to this array given `B[0]` and `B[1]`?

Here's how you can proceed with just two arrays:

```
set B = B[0]
while B[1] not empty:
    for each b in B[1]:
        if b not in B:
            append b to B
            remove b from B[1]
        else:
            remove b from B
    increment each of the remaining elements in B[1] by 1
return length(B)
```

You have to mimic binary addition via the elements of the B arrays.

To get the number of bits set, you just return the number of elements in B.

Comment: No. How to get it only if we know the positions of bits set.Also we want to get count of set positions only

Comment: their are not only 2 elements in array B

Comment: Your example result is wrong; it should be `1011100100 or [2,*5*,6,7,9]`. Your algorithm is clearly wrong after the edit; 'append b to B' and then 'remove b from B' is a no-op. What you want is something more like: while exists some b in B[1] not in B THEN add to B and remove from B[1] ELSE remove from B and B[1] but add **one** incremented value b+1 to B[1] (representing the carry).

Answer (score 0):

So given the array `B`, you want to calculate the sum of the elements of `A`, 740 in this example?

Easy:

```
int sum = 0;
foreach( var bSubArray in B)
    foreach( var b in bSubArray)
        sum += Power( 2, b);
```

Comment: Can't their be any faster way ?? I want to use the fact that I know the positions of set bits of numbers in A.

Comment: If you're only given the array `B`, you have to look at every element of `B`.